# Pivoting rows into columns with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Am learning to create a user-user collaborative recommender system, where I read the implicit data from my MySql database with the help of Python: MySql_Connector. With the Purchase data, am trying to create a user * item rating matrix, for which am Pivoting the rows(700,000 rows) into columns with pandas. Am getting the following error when I run pivot with the entire data frame.

**"ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow"**

```py
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mysql.connector import errorcode
def readData():
    try:
        mySQLConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='testdb',
                                             user='user',
                                             password='pwd')
        cursor = mySQLConnection.cursor(prepared=True)
        sql_select_query = """""" #Removed the select query
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        return record
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to get record from database: {}".format(error))
    finally:
        # closing database connection.
        if (mySQLConnection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            mySQLConnection.close()
            print("connection is closed")

data = readData()
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['user_id','product_id','purchase_count'])
data_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['user_id'],columns=df['product_id'])
#print(data_pivot.to_string())
```

python_version : 3.6
os : win7
ram : 16gb
pandas_version : 0.24.2

Comment: It's easier to perform such queries in the *database*. [This article](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot) shows how you can pivot data in MySQL. What do you want to do with this data though? If you have a lot of products it will be impossible to display the pivoted table. It can be exported eg to a CSV or Excel file, but the file will be very hard to use. The `user, product, count` format is better.

Comment: If you really really want to pivot all the data, first consider that eg 1000 users by 1000 products produce 1M rows, whether they purchased something or not. If you still want to do this, notice that you *don't* need to load all users, while you *do* need to load all products. This means that you can page your data by `user_id` and pivot one result page at a time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I couldn't pivot with MySQL because I have to use CASE statement for 10000+ products. My intention is to create a Rating Matrix for user-user collaborative filtering.

Comment: how are you going to use a dataframe with 10K columns then? The row form is easier to search, especially if the fields are indexed. Which once again means the results would be more useful if they were stored in a database. In any case, if you do want to pivot, you'll have to load the data for a few users at a time